# java ATM program simulation with exception handling - no error neither full output

Tags: java, checked-exceptions

the output is not a complete one, and neither are the exceptions handled.
Please help.

```
public class ATM {

    private String message;

    public ATM(String m) {
        if (m == null || m.trim().equals(""))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("ATM name cannot be empty");
        else {
            message = m;
            System.out.println("Name is   " + message);
        }
    }

    // public String getMessage() {
    // return message;
    // }

    public void withdraw(Card c, double amount) throws NotEnoughMoneyInAccountException {
        double bal = c.getBalance();

        System.out.println(bal);

        if (c == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("card cannot be null");
        if (amount < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("please enter amount");
        if (bal > amount)
        throw new NotEnoughMoneyInAccountException("money in account is less");
        else {
            bal = bal - amount;
            c.setBalance(bal);
            System.out.println(bal);
        }
    }

    public void deposit(Card c, double amount) {
        double bal = c.getBalance();

        if (amount == 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Please enter amount to deposit");
        bal = bal + amount;
        System.out.println(bal);
    }
}


public class Card {
    private double balance;
    private String owner;
    public double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }
    public void setBalance(double balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }
    public String getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }
    public void setOwner(String owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }
}

public class NotEnoughMoneyInAccountException extends Exception
{
    public NotEnoughMoneyInAccountException(String m)
    {
        super(m);
    }
}

public class TestATM {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try
        {
            System.out.println("Starting");
            Card c1 = new Card();
            c1.setOwner("Shweta");
            c1.setBalance(500);

            System.out.println(c1.getOwner());

            ATM atm = new ATM("SBI");
            atm.withdraw(c1, 200);
            atm.deposit(c1, 200);
        }
        catch (NotEnoughMoneyInAccountException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.getMessage();
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

the output is :

```
Starting
Shweta
Name is   SBI
500.0
```

When I enter the atm name (String message) as null, the exception should be handled accordingly, but that does not happen.
Even when I enter amount to withdraw < 0, it should enter the if loop and throw an exception which must be handled in the main program, neither does that happen.

Neither do I get any kind of error.

Comment: You should use an IDE and learn to debug your programs. It will allow you to follow step-by-step what happens when you enter a null value.

Comment: @AlexM a developer should very easily be able to solve this without an IDE. If not, he really shouldn't be using an IDE (yet)

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is here:

```
 catch (NotEnoughMoneyInAccountException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.getMessage();
}

catch(Exception e)
{
    e.getMessage(); 
}
```

`e.getMessage();` will get you the message, but you don't do anything with it.
Replace those `e.getMessage();` calls by `e.printStackTrace();`